# Gradle: import test files from other module in the same project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

My Java project has 2 modules: `moduleA` and `moduleB`. Inside moduleB's tests, I want to import some test files of moduleA.

Here is the way that I defined in the moduleB gradle:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation project(":moduleA").sourceSets.test.output
}
```

By doing this, my IDE, which is IntellijIDEA, can recognize the test source files from the moduleA. However, when I run tests of moduleB, I receive the following error:

> error: package com.moduleA.test_utils does not exist

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you build the project by Gradle from the command line? And when you build it from the IntelliJ IDEA? Please provide a sample project if problem remains.